# Finding the context free language

Tags: abstract-algebra, context-free-grammar

I am a self taught  software developer and i  came to a problem which i can not solve  , can you please help me find the context free language of this language?

Thank you .

Here is the example , i am trying to find the  context free gramar.

$$\{w\in \{a,b\}^+\mid|w|_a = |w|_b+1\}$$

Comment: can you please explain a bit about the whole conception  how did you get that ,   thank you for that already.

Comment: @BinyaminR, your grammar does not produce $aaabb$. (also, you switched $a$ and $b$)

Comment: @IsaacRen can you  help us out  please?

Comment: I am thinking about your problem :)

Comment: @IsaacRen right, trying to fix

Comment: thank you guys for being so fast,  i am looking forward   for your thoughts

Comment: is there any way you could add some commentary to that?

Comment: @BinyaminR, your rules produce $aa$, which shouldn't be in the language.

Comment: Here's a slightly different, but closely related question https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22729/defining-a-context-free-grammar-for-w-in-0-1-0w-1w

Comment: @BinyaminR, the rule $S\rightarrow SS$ means that if $w$ is in the language, then so is $ww$, but clearly they cannot both satisfy the condition. Also, the rules $H\rightarrow b,P\rightarrow a,K\rightarrow b$ are unnecessary; you can replace them directly in the previous rules.

Comment: @IsaacRen I don't think SS means that, because I added the first var S', which forces the extra a (it should be an a)

Comment: Oops, you are right. My bad.

Comment: But I think the easiest thing to do, is to use what @saulspatz sent and to add a buffer var that forces an extra a

Comment: I think the only rule for $S'$ that you need is $S'\rightarrow SbS$, and you can add $S\rightarrow\varepsilon$. Also, you mistyped the rule $S\rightarrow SPSb$.

Comment: hello guys i know that i am thirdwheeling here but can you finalize your thoughts or would you agree  on the last solution that BinyaminR said?

Comment: I'm writing an answer, it'll be ready in a few minutes.

Comment: @MICHAEL my answer isn't very good, I'm erasing it, wait for Isaac Rens answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, saulspatz referenced a very useful question https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22729/defining-a-context-free-grammar-for-w-in-0-1-0w-1w. BinyaminR also provided a solution, but I think there are some things that can be improved or corrected. Using this information, I propose the following rules:
$$S\rightarrow S'aS' \\ S'\rightarrow aS'bS' \\ S'\rightarrow bS'aS' \\ S'\rightarrow\varepsilon$$
Using the referenced question, we can check that the language generated from $S'$ is $\{w\mid|w|_a=|w|_b\}$ (This is non trivial). In order to prove that our CFG produces $L_0:=\{w\mid|w|_a=|w|_b+1\}$, we can once again proceed by double inclusion.

Denote by $L$ the language produced by our CFG. If $w\in L$, then $w$ is of the form $uau'$ where $u$ and $u'$ have the same number of $a$ and $b$. Therefore $w\in L_0$. Therefore, $L\subseteq L_0$.

Conversely, let $w\in L_0$, and let $n=|w|$. Denote by $w_{\leq k}$ the first $k$ letters of $w$, and $f(k):=|w_{\leq k}|_a-|w_{\leq k}|_b$. Then
$$\forall k\in\{1,\ldots,n-1\},\quad f(k+1)=f(k)\pm1,$$
depending on if the $(k+1)^\text{th}$ letter is an $a$ or a $b$. Thus $f$ increments by $\pm1$. Since $f(0)=0$ and $f(n)=1$, there must exist $k\geq1$ where $f(k)=0$ and $f(k+1)=1$, i.e. the $(k+1)^\text{th}$ letter of $w$ is an $a$, and $|w_{\leq k}|_a=|w_{\leq k}|_b$. Therefore we can write
$$w=w_{\leq k}aw',$$
where $w'$ is just the rest of the word. We calculate that $|w'|_a=|w'|_b$ as well, so $w_{\leq k}$ and $w'$ are both produced by $S'$, so $w$ is produced by $S$, so $w\in L$. Therefore, $L_0\subseteq L$.

Thus, by double inclusion, $L=L_0$.

---

Sorry it's a bit long ^^ for future reference, these kinds of questions about formal languages are probably more appropriate in the CS StackExchange.

Comment: whoa ,thank you so much  for that one

Comment: You are very welcome :)

Comment: one more question , it may sound silly but  the " : " and the " | "  characters are similar when it comes to context free grammar   , just because you suggested an edit  ,  my example looked like that \{w\in \{a,b\}^+ : |w|_a = |w|_b+1\}   without the | line in it  but with colon in between,   i delete this question after that ,just i am curios

Comment: I have a personal preference for $\mid$, but in this case it would be clearer with $:$, you are correct. So if you want, you can edit it back. Also, I don't think you need to delete this question. There's no reason to, and if anyone happens to have the same problem they can find it here.

Comment: thank you have a great day.